# "Je suis venu pour parler d’une seule chose" vs "Je suis venu parler d’une seule chose"

Tags: usage, infinitif, registre

D'un discours de l'homme politique Jean-Luc Mélenchon :

> "Je suis venu pour parler d’une seule chose : la pauvreté. La pauvreté explose."

Je sais que venir peut être suivi par un infinitif pour exposer le but.

> "Je suis venu parler d’une seule chose.

Y a-t-il des différences entre les deux tournures ? (Registre, tournure plus courante, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il n'y a aucune différence de sens entre ces deux constructions. La plus fréquente dans l'ensemble de la langue (langue du passé et langue contemporaine) est « venu parler » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=venu+parler%2Cvenu+pour+parler&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvenu%20parler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvenu%20pour%20parler%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cvenu%20parler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvenu%20pour%20parler%3B%2Cc0)). Cependant, il semble que de nos jours « venu pour parler » soit préféré à « venu parler ». La supériorité de la fréquence dans toute la langue serait due à un fort usage de « venu parler » dans le passé. On peut dire que la tournure qui comprend la préposition est plus explicite et donc préférable.
Le registre est le même pour les deux ; je dirais que c'est le registre courant, c'est à dire entre soutenu et familier.